# Large set systems such each set has at least one unique element

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Consider a ground set of $n$ elements. I am interested in the following question. What is the largest number $m$ (in terms of $n$) such that there exists a collection of $m$ sets $S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_m$ such that for all $i$:

$$
S_i \setminus(\cup_{j \neq i}S_j) \neq \emptyset.
$$

I wonder if there is an explicit answer. If not, is there any non-trivial large $m$ such that such a system is guaranteed to exist?

Comment: Isn't the optimum achieved by taking $n$ distinct singletons?

Comment: maybe I'm confused: The largest $m$ possible is $n$.

Assume the family $F$ exists, let $X$ be the numbers that appear in exactly one set. There is an injective function from $F$ to $X$ that maps each set to a unique element.

$m=n$ is achievable if and only if $X$ has size $n$, in other words $F$ must be a partition of the ground set into $n$ parts, which is possible if and only if every element is a singleton.

Comment: I think you're right. I think I was terribly confused for a moment there.